# NodeJS - Return always pending, but console.log shows correct data

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, async-await

I am having a hard time understanding, why my Async function correctly logs data from Database, but when I want to return the data, it always: Promise { pending }.

Here's my **getUsers.js**:

```html
const express = require('express');
var router = ('express-promise-router');
const config = require('../../config/config.json');

const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
    user: config.database.username,
    host: config.database.ip,
    database: 'portal',
    password: config.database.password,
    port: config.database.port,
})

async function getUsers(){
  await pool.connect();
  
  const res = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM usr.users');
  //console.log(res);
  return res;
  await pool.end();
}

module.exports = getUsers;
```

I tried almost every type of async function (no matter if promise or callback) and I always get correct data immediately when I try to `console.log(res)`. But when I try to return res -> I get `Promise { < pending > }`

Here is the **index.js** where I call this middleware function:

```html
const config = require('./config/config.json');
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
//const getTasks = require('./middleware/getTasks');
const getUsers = require('./middleware/pgsql/getUsers');
const users = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();
//app.use(getTasks);
app.use(getUsers);
app.use('/api/users', users);

const allusers = getUsers();
console.log(allusers);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}...`));
```

No matter what I try, I am unable to retrieve my users array in **index.js**. I am using npm PG and postgress sql database. What am I missing?

Comment: `getUsers` return `Promise<typeof res>`, so `const allusers = await getUsers()` or `getUsers().then(allUsers => console.log(allUsers))`

Comment: async functions are returning promises.

Comment: I think you should call `return Promise.resolve("next");` since getUsers is a middleware function. Also `await pool.end();` will never be called since it is below the `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks everyone, my issue was lack of understanding.. this kind of implementation shouldn't have been an middleware function , but simple route that calls database directly - which works beautifuly. Thanks again.